# Spring MVC 3.0 handling data

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-3

I'm learning Spring MVC 3 and I'm stuck on I guess a simple issue. I have a View calculator that takes 2 integers in a form. These are passed into my form pojo. My Controller adds and then prints to Catlina.out log. I want to pass my int sum; back to the view how can I acheive this.

Here's initial View

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="a">First Number</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="a" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="b">Second Number</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="b" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Numbers"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

here's my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNumbers", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public String addNumbers(@ModelAttribute("calculator")
    Calculator calculator, BindingResult result) {

        System.out.println(calculator.getA() + calculator.getB());
        return "redirect:calculator.html";

    }
```

Updated After initial question was answered, I have added a new view to display result and changed my controller:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Syed Shah</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Results</h2>

 ${calculator.A}

<a href="calculator.html">Back to Calculator</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My Calculator Instance:

```
package webcalculator.form;


//import webcalculator.domain.Numbers;

public class Calculator {


    private int A;
    private int B;
    private int sum;

    public int getA() {
        return A;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        A = a;
    }


    public int getB() {
        return B;
    }
    public void setB(int b) {
        B = b;
    }


    public int getAddSum(){
        sum = A+B;
        return sum;
    }


}
```

My new controller:

```
public class CalculatorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addNumbers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addNumbers(Calculator calculator, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        //System.out.println(calculator.getA() + calculator.getB());
        model.addAttribute("calculator", calculator);
        return "result"; // notice no redirect

    }
```

Stack Trace:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/result.jsp at line 9
>
> 6:  7:
>
> ### Results
>
> 8:   9:  ${calculator.getAddSum} 10:
>   11: Back to Calculator 12:
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'getAddSum' not found on
>   type webcalculator.form.Calculator
>     javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:214)
>     javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:191)
>     javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:300)
>     javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:81)
>     javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
>     org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:938)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.result_jsp._jspService(result_jsp.java:69)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: Your form doesn't seem to match your handler method. Look into flash attributes since you are doing a redirect.

Comment: Sotirios I am recieving the data from the form ok, as System.out.println(calculator.getA() + calculator.getB()); prints out the sum of these values. What I really want is to pass the sum back to the view not Catalina.log

Answer (score 0):

Typically how you would do this is add your Object to the Model and return a view name.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNumbers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNumbers(Calculator calculator, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    System.out.println(calculator.getA() + calculator.getB());
    model.addAttribute("calculator", calculator);
    return "myViewName"; // notice no redirect

}
```

Here, I assume your `Calculator` object contains the sum like `calculator.getSum()`. In a jsp, you can then do

```
${calculator.sum}
```

to retrieve the sum.

The above would also (probably) work without the `Model` and with the `@ModelAttribute` that you previously had. However, a `ModelAttribute` is only good for the scope of one request. All model attributes are added to the request attributes at some point during Spring's processing and are then available in the jsp you dispatch to.

However, since you do a `redirect`, a new request is made and your request attributes are lost. If you still want to do a redirect, you will have to use `RedirectAttributes/FlashAttributes` which are temporarily "persisted" in the session. Ctrl+F for them [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Comment: what I really want is values added together and the result passed back to a new view or the ideally the same view.  I would like something like return newView(sumOfAttributes).

Comment: @syed You have `a` and `b`, just add them up in a `sum` variable in the `Calculator` instance or in some other `variable`, that you then add to the model with `addAttribute()`.

Comment: My Calculator instance has addSum(adds a+B)
 but I get a stack trace: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'addSum' not found on type webcalculator.form.Calculator so I feel my Calculator instance is not being attached, I used the example you supplied above in my controller

Comment: @Syed Edit your question with the exception and your `Calculator` class.

Comment: I have added a new view result.jsp and added the ${calculator.getA} as I know Im receiving this attribute, in the jsp I have an include file that defines the core JSTL tags

Comment: Use `${calculator.A}` or `${calculator.a}` and rename your fields to `a` and `b`, lowercase. Also, don't overwrite your question, edit it. Add your old stuff back.

Comment: Sotirios I have made various attempts but still unable to access the model in my view. is it possible to instant chat.

Comment: @syed You don't have enough reputation. I would recommend reading [this documentation on spring mvc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). It might take a while, but you will be much better off to solve your problem.

Comment: ok sorted was the lowercase issue in the EL addSum() is expressed as sum. Thanks for your help Sotirios, can I mark you up anyhow??

Comment: @Syed There's a checkmark next to answers to set them as accepted for each question and little up/down arrows for give reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your exception is deeper down the stacktrace.

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'getAddSum' not found on type webcalculator.form.Calculator

So your calculator does not have this method.

Also: since your calculator is a modelattribute already you dont have to add it again as far as i know.